# What's the schedule/frequency of the bus from Kansai International Airport (KIX) to Itami International Airport (ITM)?

Tags: japan, airport-transfer, buses, timetables, osaka

I may do an airport transfer from Kansai International Airport (KIX) to Osaka International Airport (aka Itami Airport or Itami International Airport (ITM)) at the end of December. How frequently does the bus from Kansai International Airport (KIX) to Itami International Airport (ITM) operate? Or better, what's its schedule?

---

My research: I'm reading conflicting information.

- https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Osaka-Kansai-Airport-KIX/Osaka-Itami-Airport-ITM#r/Bus/s/0: "FREQUENCY: every 4 hours"
- https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k9891165-Landing_at_Osaka_KIX_and_transferring_to_ITM-Air_Travel.html: "Buses run at 30-40 minute intervals throughout the day."

I found some timetable on https://www.okkbus.co.jp/en/timetable/ITM/ too:

[image]

It indicates the bus runs every 3 to 4 hours. But perhaps there's another bus company? Or the schedule changed due to COVID-19?

Comment: Are you open to connecting somewhere?  There are a lot more options if you're willing to change trains/buses once.

Comment: @lambshaanxy thanks, this is indeed  just a connection. I was [told](https://www.reddit.com/r/JapanTravel/comments/zne4m5/weekly_japan_travel_and_tourism_discussion_thread/j0rbydr/?context=3) I could use the Haruka train from KIX airport to Shin-Osaka station, then transfer to bus to ITM airport. https://www.okkbus.co.jp/en/timetable/U/. If you know a better plan, please let me know and I'll open a question for it.

Answer (score 5):

The timetable image you have is correct. The [bus page on the official airport website](https://www.kansai-airport.or.jp/en/access/bus) links to [this website](http://www.kate.co.jp/en/timetable/detail/ITM) for Itami Airport. This website has the same timetable as the image above. Additionally, the route search (on the same page) for "Transfer to Osaka International Airport (Itami)" suggests buses which correspond to the timetable.

The Tripadvisor thread is 6 years old, I suspect the timetable changed during COVID-19.